# Best way to perform a task before ViewController change

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiviewcontroller

What's the best way to execute a given block globally at certain phases of a `UIViewController`, in particular, before a view controller is hidden from view (dismissed, another view controller pushed, etc.)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just override the builtin notifications:

```
- (void)viewWillDisappear:(BOOL)animated
{
  [super viewWillDisappear:animated];

  // Do what you need to do

}
```

Also see the [other notifications](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIViewController_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006926-CH3-DontLinkElementID_4):

```
– viewWillAppear:
– viewDidAppear:
– viewWillDisappear:
– viewDidDisappear:
– viewWillLayoutSubviews
– viewDidLayoutSubviews
```

Update: If you need to do this for all UIViewControllers in your app, you have a these choices

1. Create a custom class and have all of your ViewControllers
   inherit from your custom class
2. Method Swizzling (similar example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13865164/1804403))

Subclassing is probably the best, but if that is impractical for any reason I would look into method swizzling.

Comment: I'm aware of this, but, see my *global* specification. This solution would require me to go through each subclass (and all future subclasses) and add the code that I'd need to happen. (Also, not easily modifiable)